# MVC3 CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Step)

            @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Step)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Step)
        </div>




  <div id="tabs" title="Test">
    @if (Model !=null)
```

I keep seeing this:   CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model'
Pointing at If statment.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the model you are passing to view>

Comment: public Class Model { public int Step{get;set;} public List<string> ValuesToParse{get;set;}}

Answer (score 3):

Instead of 'Model' use something else.  Model is a class that it thinks you're trying to reference.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Step)
```